# In asp.Net, writing code in the control tag generates compile error

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Hi this is really strange !!

But look at the following asp code:

```
    <div runat="server" id="MainDiv">
      <%foreach (string str in new string[]{"First#", "Second#"})
          { %>
            <div id="<%=str.Replace("#","div") %>">
            </div>
        <%} %>
    </div>
```

now if you put this code inside any web page (and don't worry about the moral of this code, I made it just to show the idea)
you'll get this error :

Compiler Error Message: CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Of course the error has nothing to do with the real problem, I searched for the code that was generated by asp.net and figured out the following :

```
     private void @__RenderMainDiv(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter @__w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer)
    {
        @__w.Write("\r\n        ");

        #line 20 "blabla\blabla\Default.aspx"
        foreach (string str in new string[] { "First#", "Second#" })
        {

            #line default
            #line hidden
            @__w.Write("\r\n        <div id=\"");

            #line 22 "blabla\blabla\Default.aspx"
            @__w.Write(str.Replace("#", "div"));


            #line default
            #line hidden
            @__w.Write("\">\r\n        ");
     }
```

This is the code that was generated from the asp page and this is the method that is meant to render our div (MainDiv), I found out that there is a missing bracket "}" that closes the method or the (for loop).

now the problem has three parts:
1- first you should have a server control (in our situation is the MainDiv) and I'm not sure if it is only the div tag.
2- HTML control inside the server control and a code inside it using the double quotation mark ( for example `<div id="<%=str` instead of `<div id='<%=str`.
3-Any keyword which has block brackets e.g.:for{},while{},using{}...etc.

now removing any part, will solve the problem !!!

how is this happening ??
any ideas ?

BTW: please help me to make the question more obvious, because I couldn't find the best words to describe the problem.

Look like my question is not clear !!
My question is : what is the steps that asp.net follows to generate such a wrong code ??
how is that happening !!
I don't want the solution for the exception , I already solved it using single quotation.

Answer (score 6):

You can't enclose double quotes in double quotes.

```
<div id="<%=str.Replace("#","div") %>">
```

It can't tell when one is supposed to start or end which is why

```
<div id='<%=str.Replace("#","div") %>'>
```

would work.

Otherwise it thinks the code is

```
 <div id="<%=str.Replace("
 ","
 div
 ") %>"
 )
```

which of course makes no sense.

**Update based on my comment below**

Adding the `runat="server"` causes the control to be parsed by ASP.NET, otherwise it is just passed straight out as html.

If it gets parsed by ASP.NET things are different. To be honest I am not sure of the exact internal workings at play here. All I can tell you is that if the `runat="server"` attribute is set then ASP.NET parses it and it plays by different rules.

It will try to decompose the inner html as I described above.

If the `runat="server"` attribute is removed then it is passed out as html, hence the inline code is processed then just pushed out with the surrounding html, regardless of what it is, e.g. double quotes.

Comment: but if you keep using the double quotes and for example remove the runat="server" from the main div, the problem will be solved ??? so the problem is not in the double quotes!!!

Comment: Well not really. Adding the runat="server" causes the control to be parsed by ASP.NET, otherwise it is just passed straight out as html. If it gets parsed by ASP.NET things are different. To be honest I am not sure of the exact internal workings at play here. All I can tell you is that if the runat="server" attribute is set then ASP.NET parses it and it plays by different rules. It will most likely try to decompose the inner Html as I described above in my answer.

Comment: @Downvoter - normally its courteous to comment with why it was downvoted so we have the opportunity to enhance the answer.

Comment: @Nour - Did I clarify my answer or did you need further explanation?

Comment: considering the first point, I actually don't agree with you. if you noticed the generated code : 
            @__w.Write(str.Replace("#", "div"));
you will see that this line is correct, and that exactly what should be parsed !!

Comment: Read just above Listing 3 on this page http://west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp#_Page_Parsing. It explains a situation very similar and how if you have inline code within a control with runat="server" it needs to override the rendering of the particular container. The code required for rendering in your particular case is that complex that it is bound to have limitations and have strange occurances happen when you do things like your example. If you want an exact reason why, you need to read the code of ASP.NET parser. :)

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me :

```
<div runat="server" id="MainDiv">
      <%foreach (string str in new string[]{"First#", "Second#"})%>
          <%{%>
          <% string str1 = str.Replace("#","div"); %>
           <div id='<%= str1%>'>123</div> 
           <%}%>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I know how to solve the problem, and I have already solved it, but I'm just curious about the way that this error happened ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to completely figure out why the parser is doing what it is, but it is obvious from the last real code line that it has got its knickers in a twist.

> @__w.Write("\">\r\n        ");

This is putting out **">**  and not just **>** - this is the last chevron in this statement

```
<div id="<%=str.Replace("#","div") %>">
```

So, at this point the parser believes it is in a string, but finds no terminator, so fails out - this means the last

> <%} %>
>   is never being parsed - and your problem occurs.

I would suggest that this is because the parser is working in a linear fashion and it is not until the missing string terminator is 'discovered' that the fail happens.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange and it's likely an issue with using that type of syntax with webforms, but I was able to get this code to compile and the render the divs to the page:

```
<div runat="server" id="MainDiv">
  <%foreach (string str in new string[] {"First#", "Second#"})
      {%>
        <div id='<%= string.Format("{0}", str.Replace("#","div")) %>'>
            Testing
        </div>
    <%}%>
</div>
```

Comment: @NourSabouny: The problem is the double quotes. The above code compiles and renders the output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes instead of double

Comment: My friend, I already mentioned the solution in my question, and you're not answering my question !!!